# make: 2 dependencies expected but only 1 exists

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Lets assume I have a little project with the following make-file.
Please attention to the generation of the o-file (2 dependencies - to the .cpp and the .hpp).

```
LIB_OPTS = -lpthread
CPP_OPTS = -std=c++11 -Wall

all: main
   ${CXX} ${CPP_OPTS} ${LIB_OPTS} *.o -o main

main: a.o b.o c.o main.o

%.o: %.cpp %.hpp
    ${CXX} ${CPP_OPTS} ${LIB_OPTS} -g -c $< -o $@

clean:
   rm *.o
```

a, b and c do have cpp and hpp-files.

main does only have a .cpp.

Here is the output.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -lpthread -g -c a.cpp -o a.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -lpthread -g -c b.cpp -o b.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -lpthread -g -c c.cpp -o c.o
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -lpthread *.o -o main
```

What about the generation of main.o???

Where does that come from? Thats nothing to do with my rule.

If I have a main.hpp it would catch my rule.
Sure I can create a separate rule for main.o but I expected %.o to make it.

Thanks for help!
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make has a number of built-in rules.  Among them is a rule that knows how to create a `.o` file from a `.cpp` file.  Since none of your rules are able to create `main.o`, make looks through its own built-in rules and finds one that it can use.

You can see a complete list of built-in rules using a command such as:

```
make -pf/dev/null
```

You can run make so that it doesn't use any of its own built-in rules with `make -r`.